# Why I got AbandonedMutexException after release mutex?

Tags: c#, mutex

I created two projects to start different processes.
First one main method code:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "locker");
        mutex.WaitOne();
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("newFile.txt", false))
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("first");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        Console.WriteLine("end");
    }
```

Second one:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("locker");
        try
        {
            mutex.WaitOne();
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        }
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\main\main\bin\Debug\net5.0\newFile.txt", true))
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("test");
            }
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        mutex.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("end");
    }
```

I run the first project and after the second why I got AbandonedMutexException, if I realese mutex?

Comment: Is it possible that the first process has failed before `mutex.ReleaseMutex();`?

Comment: @GuruStron no, it's always successfully completed

Comment: Is it because the first process finished and the mutex doesn't exist, when you try to access it with OpenExisting from the second process?

Comment: @funatparties mutex exist in second process

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is thrown when one thread acquires a Mutex object that another thread has abandoned by exiting without releasing it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.abandonedmutexexception?view=net-6.0

Comment: but I release mutex in the first process.

Comment: I'd try to also dispose it.

Comment: @ I thought this way, try to use dispose and close, but it gave me nothing